# No se muestra saltos de linea en mensaje de PHP MAILER

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios, phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente código para registrar datos a mi formulario:

```
$nombreEmpresa = $_POST['nombre_empresa'];
$razonSocial = $_POST['razon_social'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pin = $_POST['pin'];
$representanteLegal = $_POST['representante_legal'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$numeroEmpleados = $_POST['numero_empleados'];
$rangoEmpleados = $_POST['rango_empleados'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$categorias = isset($_POST['categorias']) ? $_POST['categorias'] : null;
```

y también utilizo PHP MAILER para enviar mensaje de bienvenida al usuario con el email con el que se registro:

```
mail->Username = "micorreo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mipass";
$mail->setFrom('micorreo@gmail.com', 'MI PAGINA');
$mail->addAddress($email, $representanteLegal);
$mail->Subject = 'BIENVENIDO '.$representanteLegal;
$mail->Body = 'Gracias por su registro a nuestro sistema apreciable: 
'.$representanteLegal.'\n'
.'Sus Datos de acceso son los siguientes: '.'\n'
.'Nombre Empresa: '.$nombreEmpresa.'\n'
.'Mail: '.$email.'\n'
.'Password: '.$password.'\n'
.'PIN: '.$pin.'\n';
```

NECESITO AYUDA YA QUE EN EL MENSAJE RECIBIDO LOS SALTOS DE LINEA NO ME LOS RECONOCE Y SÓLO LOS IMPRIME ASÍ "\n" ¿QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO MAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utiliza comillas dobles para que los caracteres especiales como "\n" funcionen, ademas te recomiendo que el cuerpo del documento lo escribas rompiendo el parrafo en menos de 70 caracteres por linea, puedes hacerlo con la funcion `wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n")`

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me ayudaste mucho¡

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la constante predefinida `PHP_EOL` que provee PHP para estos casos:

```
$mail->Body = 'Gracias por su registro a nuestro sistema apreciable: '
    .$representanteLegal.PHP_EOL
    .'Sus Datos de acceso son los siguientes: '.PHP_EOL
    .'Nombre Empresa: '.$nombreEmpresa.PHP_EOL
    .'Mail: '.$email.PHP_EOL
    .'Password: '.$password.PHP_EOL
    .'PIN: '.$pin.PHP_EOL;
```

Puedes conocer más sobre las [constantes predefinidas en la documentación oficial de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php).